# JRadioButton cannot be converted to ButtonModel

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I have some JRadioButtons (`suggested_radio`, `deleted_radio`, `done_radio`, ...).
I put them all in a ButtonGroup (`subTask_situation`).
I set suggested_radio to be selected `suggested_radio.setSelected(true)`.
I want this radio to be set as selected again after the user clicks on the button "add".
So, I wrote the code in actionPerformed as follows:

```
//some code
subTask_situation.setSelected(suggested_radio, true);
```

But it gives me the error: JRadioButton cannot be converted to ButtonModel

Any idea on how to reselected the `suggested_radio` after clicking on "add" button?

Comment: Or you could use the JRadioButton's model: `subTask_situation.setSelected(suggested_radio.getModel(), true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you used: ButtonGroup.setSelected(...) actually takes in a parameter of ButtonModel not a JRadioButton. Instead of doing that, just make the radio button to be set selected true with the same code that you wrote above: `suggested_radio.setSelected(true)`

Read the API's for more information on radio buttons: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/RadioButtonDemoProject/src/components/RadioButtonDemo.java

For a button group: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html